# Long not converting to String

Tags: python, google-app-engine, long-integer, cherrypy

I'm trying to get this function working in Google App Engine using Python:

```
def textarea(id):
    variable = brfsscodegenerator.Variable.get_by_id(int(id))
    varID = variable.key().id()
    textarea = ("<tr><td>" + variable.name + "</td><td>" + variable.year + 
            "</td><td><textarea id='textarea' name='qtext_" + str(varID) + "'>" )
    return textarea
```

But I get this error (I'm using CherryPy):

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

I've tested to see that varID is actually returning a number, but it still doesn't seem to want to convert, and I know my quotation marks are in order as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What line?  Posting the full traceback is usually helpful in these circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `variable.year` is a string or convert it too.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not automatically format numbers as strings when you attempt to concatenate a string with one. This is a deliberate design choice, as a result of one of Python's guiding principles, "explicit is better than implicit". You can convert the number with `str(num)`, but a better way to do this would be to use string formatting throughout, like this:

```
textarea = "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%d</td><td><textarea id='textarea' name='qtext_%d'>" % (variable.name, variable.year, varID)
```

A better approach again would be to use a templating system instead of interpolating strings yourself. The risk of introducing an XSS error doing things this way is high, and your code's a lot less readable.